# Illegal assignment from SObject to Contact

Tags: apex

I am getting the following error:

> Illegal assignment from SObject to Contact

I created a class called DynamicSObjectUpdater that I use to consolidate DML statements in my triggers. Basically you just call the class `getSObject` and it appends the SObject to a Map called `sorToUpdate` and then returns the SObject.

In one of my classes, I am calling the Class and its saying the following code is an illegal assignment from SObject to Contact.

```
Contact conToUpdate = sObjectUpdater.getSObject(con.Id);
```

I am not sure what I am missing here to make this work.

```
public with sharing class DyanmicSObjectUpdater {

    Map<SObjectType, Map<Id, sObject>> sorToUpdate = new Map<SObjectType, Map<Id, sObject>>();

    public SObject getSObject(ID sObjectID)
    {
        SObjectType sot = sObjectID.getSobjectType();

        if(!sorToUpdate.containsKey(sot))
        {
            sorToUpdate.put(sot, new Map<Id, SObject>());
        }

        SObject targetSObject = sorToUpdate.get(sot).get(sObjectID);

        if(targetSObject == null)
        {
            targetSObject = sObjectID.getSobjectType().newSobject(sObjectID);
            sorToUpdate.get(sot).put(sObjectID, targetSObject);
        }

        return targetSObject;
    }


    public void updateSObjects()
    {

        List<SObject> sObjectsToUpdate = new List<SObject>();
        if(sObjectsToUpdate.size() > 0)
        {
            for(SObjectType sorType: sorToUpdate.keySet())
            {
                sObjectsToUpdate.addAll(sorToUpdate.get(sorType).values());
            }
        }

        if(sObjectsToUpdate.size()>0) update sObjectsToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to cast the return value.

```
Contact conToUpdate = (Contact)sObjectUpdater.getSObject(con.Id);
```

More generally, you cannot directly assign a value typed at compile time as a superclass (like `sObject`) to a variable typed as a subclass (`Contact` is a subclass of `sObject`). You can perform a cast to tell the compiler that the `sObject` instance you're getting back from `getSObject()` is actually a `Contact`; if at runtime this is not the case (i.e., you get back an `Account` or something else that isn't a `Contact`), you will receive an exception.

You might find the implementation of the Unit of Work pattern in [`fflib`](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-apex-common) interesting as you're building this type of generic/abstracted DML code.

Comment: Thank you for the insight on this. I am beginning to learn generic/abstracted coding patterns. Let me know if you have any resources that you can point me to that you found helpful when you were beginning to learn these topics.

Comment: @MatthewMetros That's a good question, and I don't have a great answer for you. Reading good code from major Salesforce open source projects is certainly one route.

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast the result

```
Contact conToUpdate = (Contact) sObjectUpdater.getSObject(con.Id);
```